# Unable to update URL and redirect to protected route after signin while using next-auth

Tags: authentication, next.js, middleware, next-auth, next.js14

I am using next-auth. I have a page '/contact-us.tsx' which is protected and defined in matcher middleware. when the user is not logged and try to access the "/contact-us" page, then user is directed to login page and url becomes (http://localhost:3003/login?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3003%2Fcontact-us), when the user puts correct credentials, then there are two different behaviours.

1. Sometimes, user is stayed on the same url even after correct credentials. However when I click multiple times on login button, then it will directed to 'contact-us' page but the url is still not changed(same as previous: http://localhost:3003/login?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3003%2Fcontact-us)
2. Sometimes, It is directed to 'contact-us' page in the first attempt
   of correct credentials, but the url does not change to
   "localhost:3003/contact-us' instead it is same as above.

In both cases when the user is directed to "contact-us" page but the url in browser is different i-e still contain login and callback which is shown above. Now in the header when I click again on contact-us page, it gives an error and warning in browser console:

- Warning: component (`HotReload`) while rendering a different
  component (`Router`). To locate the bad setState() call inside
  `Router`, follow the stack trace
- Error: react-dom.development.js:8585 Uncaught Error: SEGMENT MISMATCH
  at serverPatchReducer (server-patch-reducer.js:47:19) at
  clientReducer

For other protected pages, it works perfectly but for the only one page which is accessed before logged in, this issue exist. So the issue is not only for 'contact-us' page but any protected page if accessed before login. so If I try to login "/help",then same issue exist for '/help' but works correctly for '/contact-us'Below is code of related files,
**//middleware.ts**

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";
export const config = { matcher: ['/help/:path*','/contact-us' };
```

**/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts**

```
import { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider
 from "next-auth/providers/credentials"; 
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next"; 
import { UserType } from "@/lib/types"; 
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = { 
pages: { signIn: "/login",signOut:'/login'     },
 session: { strategy: "jwt",     }, 
jwt: { secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,}, 
providers: [ CredentialsProvider({ name: "Credentials",
 credentials: { email: { label: "email", 
type: "text", placeholder: "example@gmail.com",  },
 password: { label: "Password", type: "password", },}, 
async authorize(credentials,req) {

const response = await fetch(${process.env.
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}
/auth/login, { method: "POST",
 headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", },
 body: JSON.stringify(credentials), });
const result = await response.json();

if(!response.ok){
 throw new Error("email or password is incorrect"); }
const access_token = "Bearer "+result.data.access_token;
const firstName = result.data.first_name; 
return { id: 'dummyId', firstName, access_token }   },  }), ], 
callbacks: { 
async jwt({ token, user })
 { if (user) token.user = user as UserType; 
return token;       }, 
async session({ token, session }) { 
session.user = token.user; return session;  },},  };
const handler = NextAuth(authOptions); 
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

**/login.tsx**

```
'use client'

type PropType = { searchParams: { callbackUrl?: string;     }} 
type Inputs = z.infer<typeof loginSchema> 

const LoginPage = ({ searchParams }:PropType) => { 
const router = useRouter() 
const { register, handleSubmit,reset,
formState: { errors }  } = 
useForm<Inputs>({resolver: zodResolver(loginSchema)})

const submitForm: SubmitHandler<Inputs> =
 async data => { const result = await 
signIn("credentials", 
{ redirect:false,email: data.email,
password: data.password,});

if (!result?.ok) { toast.error(result?.error || "") return;    } 
router.push(searchParams?.callbackUrl?searchParams?.callbackUrl:"/");   }
return (
 <main>

 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitForm)}>
 <div className="form-group">
 <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label">
Email Address</label>
<input type="text" {...register('email')} className={form-control ${errors.email?.message ? "is-invalid":""}} id="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" required /> 
<div className="form-group"> <label htmlFor="password" className="form-label">Password</label> <input type="password"
 {...register('password')} className={form-control 
${errors.password?.message ? "is-invalid":""}} 
id="password" placeholder="Enter your password" required /> 
<div className="form-group"> 
<button className="btn btn-primary" 
title="Sign In">Continue</button> </div>

 </form>

  ) }
export default LoginPage
```

**header.tsx**

```
export default function HeaderComponent(){
return( <> <li className="nav-item"> <Link className="nav-link" href="/help/1">Help</Link>
 </li>
 <li className="nav-item">  
<Link className="nav-link" href="/contact-us">Contact Us</Link>
 </li>  
</>
)
```